# How do I change the class for a specific <li> inside a ASP.NET listview ?

Tags: asp.net, css, listview

The idea is for a menu. I need to highlight the menu a specific color depending on which top node is clicked.. So if I just needed to highlight it with ONE color I could say

```
 <li <%# (Container.DataItem as FigLeafMenuItem).ItemSelected == "True" ? @" class=""MainMenuSelectedBlue""" : @" class=""""" %>>
```

But I need to change the color depending on some peice of server side info.. The closest I have gotten is below.. How do I access that specific LI so I can add a class to it?

```
 protected void lvMainOuter_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        ListViewDataItem lvdi = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
        FigLeafMenuItem flmi  = (FigLeafMenuItem)lvdi.DataItem;

        if (flmi.Name == "About Us")
        {
            HtmlGenericControl hgc = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("xxx");
            hgc.Attributes.Add("class", "MainMenuSelectedBlue");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a predictable relationship between the index of the selected nodes and the target list items?

Comment: not sure what you mean ? I just need to be able to change the class of a specific <li>... in this example I check if the Name = "About us".... So the problem is really just how do I access that specific LI it is currently on  ?

Comment: Is it really a ListView or a ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access html tag from code behind without `runat="server"`. However, you can render entire `li` tag using literal control.

```
<asp:Literal id="MenuItemLiteral" runat="server" />

if (flmi.Name == "About Us")
{
  var literal = (Literal)e.Item.FindControl("MenuItemLiteral");
  literal.Text = string.format("<li class=\"{0}\">{1}</li>", DATA1, DATA2);
}
```